# How do I use scrapy in different versions of python

Tags: python, scrapy

I enter 'scrapy crawl PROJECT_NAME' in terminal and try to run a project coded with python2 but terminal tries to use scrapy in python3 and keeps reporting error(I have scrapy library for both python2/3).

It could recognise python version of my project at first. But it fails to work now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just specify the python you want to run `scrapy` with:

```
python2 -m scrapy crawl PROJECT_NAME
```

Or even more precise:

```
/path/to/python/executable/python -m scrapy crawl PROJECT_NAME
```